# Using Materialize `chip` and `autocomplete` in Ruby on Rails Form with Associated Models

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

I am trying to create a form so a user can save a `setting` which has their default `teams` (multiple) and their `professions` (single). I can do this using `simple_form` and the lines of code below, but I am trying to use autocomplete as the dropdown lists do not work well with my design.

- `<%= f.association :profession %>`
- `<%= f.association :team, input_html: { multiple: true } %>`

I am loading the JSON from a collection into an attribute `data-autocomplete-source` within my `inputs`, a short bit of `jquery` then cycles through each of these and then initialises the materialize `.autocomplete`, I also need to do this with `.chips` for many associations.

The UI element is working as I would like, but I cannot work out how to save a new record. I have two problems:

1. `Unpermitted parameters: :team_name, :profession_name` - I've been trying to adapt this [tutorial](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3701-Auto-Complete-Association-in-Rails-5) and believed that Step 11 would effectively translate this within the model, but am clearly not understanding something...
2. `"setting"=>{"team_name"=>"", "profession_name"=>"Consultant Doctor"}` - the `team_name` values (i.e. the `chips`) are not being recognised when attempting to save the record. I've got some nasty jquery that transfers the `id` from the `div` to the generated `input` which I was hoping would work...

I've also checked many previous questions on Stack Overflow (some of which seem to be similar to this question, generally using jqueryui) but cannot work out how to adapt the answers.

**How can I use the names from a model in a materialize `chip` and `autocomplete` input and save the selections by their associated `id` into a record?**

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

---

**setting.rb**

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :team, optional: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession

  def team_name
    team.try(:name)
  end

  def team_name=(name)
    self.team = Team.find_by(name: name) if name.present?
  end

  def profession_name
    profession.try(:name)
  end

  def profession_name=(name)
    self.profession = Profession.find_by(name: name) if name.present?
  end


end
```

**settings_controller.rb**

```
  def new

    @user = current_user
    @professions = Profession.all
    @teams = Team.all
    @setting = Setting.new

    @teams_json = @teams.map(&:name)
    @professions_json = @professions.map(&:name)

    render layout: "modal"

  end


  def create

    @user = current_user
    @setting = @user.settings.create(setting_params)

    if @setting.save 
      redirect_to action: "index"
    else
      flash[:success] = "Failed to save settings"
      render "new"   
    end

  end


  private

    def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit(:user_id, :contact, :view, :taketime, :sortname, :sortlocation, :sortteam, :sortnameorder, :sortlocationorder, :sortteamorder, :location_id, :profession_id, :department_id, team_ids: [])
    end
```

**views/settings/new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @setting do |f| %>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field autocomplete_dynamic col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">group</i>

        <div data-autocomplete-source='<%= @teams_json %>' class="string optional chips" type="text" name="setting[team_name]" id="setting_team_name"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field autocomplete_dynamic col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">group</i>

          <%= f.input :profession_name, wrapper: false, label: false, as: :search, input_html: {:data => {autocomplete_source: @professions_json} } %>

        <label for="autocomplete-input">Select your role</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

```js
$("*[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function() {

  var items = [];
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-autocomplete-source"));

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; ++i) {
    items[dataJSON[i]] = null;
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass("chips")) {

    $(this).chips({
      placeholder: $(this).attr("placeholder"),
      autocompleteOptions: {
        data: items,
        limit: Infinity,
        minLength: 1
      }
    });


    // Ugly jquery to give the generated input the correct id and name
    idStore = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("id", idStore + "_wrapper");
    nameStore = $(this).attr("name");
    $(this).attr("name", nameStore + "_wrapper");

    $(this).find("input").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("id", idStore);
      $(this).attr("name", nameStore);
    });


  } else {

    $(this).autocomplete({
      data: items,
    });

  }

});
```

```css
.prefix~.chips {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Materialize CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Materialize JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Material Icon Webfont -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">




<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field autocomplete_dynamic col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">group</i>

        <div data-autocomplete-source='["Miss T","Mr C","Mr D","Medicine Take","Surgery Take"]' class="string optional chips" type="text" name="setting[team_name]" id="setting_team_name"></div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field autocomplete_dynamic col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">group</i>

        <input class="string optional input-field" data-autocomplete-source='["Consultant Doctor","Ward Clerk","Nurse","Foundation Doctor (FY1)","Foundation Doctor (FY2)","Core Trainee Doctor (CT2)","Core Trainee Doctor (CT1)"]' type="text" name="setting[profession_name]"
          id="setting_profession_name">


        <label for="autocomplete-input">Select your role</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Gems and versions**

- ruby '2.5.0'
- gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
- gem 'materialize-sass'
- gem 'material_icons'
- gem
  'materialize-form'
- gem 'simple_form', '>= 4.0.1'
- gem
  'client_side_validations'
- gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'

Comment: What does your `setting_params` method in your controller look like?

Comment: Added that to the question - I have added `profession_name` there.. thinking that it would be a security risk? Thanks for you help

Comment: Your HABTM relation needs to be pluralized `teams`. I also highly recommend removing HABTM and using `has_many :through` so that you can add a field for `defaut_team`.  Problem 1 can be fixed by adding `:team_name` and `:profession_name` to `settings_controller#setting_params` in the `permit` argument hash.  For problem 2 I would read [Rails Nested Forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) and [Materialize Chips](https://materializecss.com/chips.html).  There are multiple issues concerning both.  The scope of changes needed is honestly beyond  a single question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Tom. I will never want a user to create a team from within this form, only create associations with existing ones. Is a nested approach still the best? Happy to look into it in more detail if it is. Thanks again

Comment: If you are not modifying or creating tags then you will not need to do a nested form.  Sorry for the misunderstanding. The `team_ids: []` is correct.  You will need your autocomplete input to return the chips under `name="setting[team_ids][]"`.  The empty brackets are necessary for Rails to parse it into an array.  Out of curiosity, why are you not using form helpers?

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom, I've now worked out the autocomplete element of the form, and am currently working on the chips (i.e. the team array). The current issue I am googling is getting Rails to see a `<div>` as the form input (Materialize adds the chips to this div, and uses an input within it to allow the user to add more chips, so the form is just seeing this empty div at the moment).

Comment: I wasn't using form helpers because I was struggling to assign the JSON to a custom data attribute... the code is subtly different depending on the type of input within simple_form (i.e. `input_html: { data: { autocomplete: @professions_json  } } ` works for `f.input` but you need to use  `data: { autocomplete: @professions_json  }` for `f.text_field`.  I have now worked this out... but it wasn't the most obvious thing to a beginner! I am now back to form helpers (with the exception of the chips which needs to be a div for Materialize to initialise)

Comment: Managed to it out! I was doing a few things wrong... thanks for your help Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **This is almost certainly not the best way of doing this, *but it does work***. Please offer suggestions and I will update this, or if someone adds a better answer I will happily mark it as correct. This solution doesn't require much in the way of controller/model changes and is largely done with a (comparatively) short bit of jquery/JS so can be easily repeated within a project.

---

I've managed to get both autocomplete and chips working with Ruby on Rails, utilising simple_form form helpers where possible.

Effectively I am storing the JSON into a custom attribute for each case and then parsing this with some jquery/javascript when the view is loaded before using this to initialise either `autocomplete` or `chips`.

Autocomplete values are translated from name to id within the controller.

Chip values are recognised client side with some JS, and inputs created with the correct `name` and `id` for simpleform to automatically save the values as an array to the hash.

Full explaination and code is below.

Thank you to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5399937/tom) for his helpful comments and input.

---

### **`autocomplete`**

Requires you to create an input under ***variable*_name** and then add additional functions in the model to translate the name into an id for saving. Effectively following this [tutorial](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3701-Auto-Complete-Association-in-Rails-5).

```
<%= f.input :profession_name,  input_html: { data: { autocomplete: @professions_json  } } %>
```

As you can see above, the only real difference from adding a typical simple_form association is the following:

- `f.input` rather than `f.association` - ensures a textbox is rendered rather than a drop down
- `:model_name` rather than `:model` - ensures that the controller recognises this is a name that needs to be converted into an object
- `input_html: { data: { autocomplete: @model_json  } }` - this adds a custom attribute with all your JSON data, this is parse by

**You need to ensure the names of your model are unique.**

---

### **`chips`**

This is a little more involved, requiring extra javascript functions. The code attachs a callback to the event of adding or removing a chip, before cycling through each and adding a hidden `input`. Each input has a name attribute which matches what simple_form expects, so it is correctly added to the hash params before being submitted to the controller. I couldn't get it to translate multiple names in an array, so just got it to re-read the id from the original JSON and add that as the value of the input.

```
  <div id="team_ids" placeholder="Add a team" name="setting[team_ids]" class="chips" data-autocomplete="<%=  @teams_json %>"></div>
```

From above you can see there are the following deviations from simple_form convention:

- `<div>` rather than a `<% f.input %>` as Materialize chips needs to be called on a div
- `placeholder="..."` this text is used as a placeholder once the chips is initialised, this can be left blank / not included
- `name="setting[team_ids]"` helps simple_form understand which model this applies to
- `class="chips"` ensures that our javascript later knows to initialise `chips` on this element
- `data-autocomplete="<%=  @teams_json %>"` saves the JSON data as an attribute of the div for parsing later

> **Currently the code re-parses the original JSON attribute**, it is possible to reference the JSON data that is created on initialisation of the chips, this is likely better but I could not get it to work.
>
> **Custom Input Element** - someone more experience than myself might be able to play around with this and create a custom element for simple_form... it was beyond me unfortunately.

---

## Ruby on Rails Code

**settings_controller.rb**

```rb
class SettingsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def new

    @user = current_user
    @setting = Setting.new
    @professions = Profession.select(:name)
    @teams = Team.select(:id, :name)

    # Prepare JSON for autocomplete and chips
    @teams_json = @teams.to_json(:only => [:id, :name] )
    @professions_json = @professions.to_json(:only => [:name] )

  end


  ....

 private
    def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit( :profession_name, :user_id,  :profession_id, team_ids: [])
    end
```

**setting.rb**

```rb
class Setting < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams, optional: true    
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession, optional: true

  def profession_name
    profession.try(:name)
  end

  def profession_name=(name)
    self.profession = Profession.find_by(name: name) if name.present?
  end
```

**_form.html.erb** *N.B. this is a partial, as denoted by the preceding underscore*

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @setting, validate: true, remote: true  do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :profession_name,  input_html: { data: { autocomplete: @professions_json  } } %>

  <div id="team_ids" placeholder="Add a team" name="setting[team_ids]" class="chips" data-autocomplete="<%=  @teams_json %>"></div>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

---

## Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Cycle through anything with an data-autocomplete attribute
  // Cannot use 'input' as chips must be innitialised on a div
  $("[data-autocomplete]").each(function() {

    var dataJSON = JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-autocomplete"));

    // Prepare array for items and add each
    var items = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; ++i) {
      items[dataJSON[i].name] = null; // Could assign id to image url and grab this later? dataJSON[i].id
    }


    // Check if component needs to be a chips
    if ($(this).hasClass("chips")) {

      // Initialise chips
      // Documentation: https://materializecss.com/chips.html
      $(this).chips({
        placeholder: $(this).attr("placeholder"),
        autocompleteOptions: {
          data: items,
          limit: Infinity,
          minLength: 1
        },
        onChipAdd: () => {
          chipChange($(this).attr("id")); // See below
        },
        onChipDelete: () => {
          chipChange($(this).attr("id")); // See below
        }
      });


      // Tweak the input names, etc
      // This means we can style the code within the view as we would a simple_form input
      $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_wrapper");

      $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + "_wrapper");

    } else {

      // Autocomplete is much simpler! Just initialise with data
      // Documentation: https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html
      $(this).autocomplete({
        data: items,
      });

    }




  });

});


function chipChange(elementID) {

  // Get chip element from ID
  var elem = $("#" + elementID);

  // In theory you can get the data of the chips instance, rather than re-parsing it
  var dataJSON = JSON.parse(elem.attr("data-autocomplete"));

  // Remove any previous inputs (we are about to re-add them all)
  elem.children("input[auto-chip-entry=true]").remove();

  // Find the wrapping element
  wrapElement = elem.closest("div[data-autocomplete].chips")

  // Get the input name we need, [] tells Rails that this is an array
  formInputName = wrapElement.attr("name").replace("_wrapper", "") + "[]";

  // Start counting entries so we can add value to input
  var i = 0;

  // Cycle through each chip
  elem.children(".chip").each(function() {

    // Get text of chip (effectively just excluding material icons 'close' text)
    chipText = $(this).ignore("*").text();

    // Get id from original JSON array
    // You should be able to check the initialised Materialize data array.... Not sure how to make that work
    var chipID = findElement(dataJSON, "name", chipText);

    // ?Check for undefined here, will be rejected by Rails anyway...?

    // Add input with value of the selected model ID
    $(this).parent().append('<input value="' + chipID + '"  multiple="multiple" type="hidden" name="' + formInputName + '" auto-chip-entry="true">');


  });

}


// Get object from array of objects using property name and value
function findElement(arr, propName, propValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i][propName] == propValue)
      return arr[i].id; // Return id only
  // will return undefined if not found; you could return a default instead
}


// Remove text from children, etc
$.fn.ignore = function(sel) {
  return this.clone().find(sel || ">*").remove().end();
};


// Print to console instead of posting
$(document).on("click", "input[type=submit]", function(event) {

  // Prevent submission of form
  event.preventDefault();

  // Gather input values
  var info = [];
  $(this).closest("form").find("input").each(function() {
    info.push($(this).attr("name") + ":" + $(this).val());
  });

  // Prepare hash in easy to read format
  var outText = "<h6>Output</h6><p>" + info.join("</br>") + "</p>";
  
  // Add to output if exists, or create if it does not
  if ($("#output").length > 0) {
    $("#output").html(outText);
  } else {
    $("form").append("<div id='output'>" + outText + "</div>");
  }


});
```

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Materialize CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Materialize JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Material Icon Webfont -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">



<form class="simple_form new_setting" id="new_setting" novalidate="novalidate" data-client-side-validations="" action="/settings" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">


  <div class="input-field col string optional setting_profession_name">
  <input data-autocomplete='[{"id":1,"name":"Consultant Doctor"},{"id":2,"name":"Junior Doctor (FY1)"}]' class="string optional" type="text" name="setting[profession_name]" id="setting_profession_name"
      data-target="autocomplete-options-30fe36f7-f61c-b2f3-e0ef-c513137b42f8" data-validate="true">
      <label class="string optional" for="setting_profession_name">Profession name</label></div>

  <div id="team_ids" name="setting[team_ids]" class="chips input-field" placeholder="Add a team" data-autocomplete='[{"id":1,"name":"Miss T"},{"id":2,"name":"Surgical Take"}]'></div>


  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Setting" data-disable-with="Create Setting">

</form>
```

Comment: Depending on the column count of your tables, you can greatly improve performance by pulling only the necessary fields with your query instead of filtering this out later in rails: `@teams = Team.all`  ==> `@teams = Team.select(:id, :name)`.

Comment: There aren't that many extra columns in most of my use cases, but will make that change. Every little helps! Thanks